# Devexpress : ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback on CallBack not firing when calling the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback, devexpress

I am trying to Reload the same page after getting the user login. The login is in a form of a dialog, On successful login. This Dialog Closes and I am trying to refresh the page. So that relevant information can be reloaded and few changes in display.

Any Suggestions ?

**Code javaScript**

```
 function ValidateLogin() {

   Page_ClientValidate("login");
   if (Page_IsValid) {
      LoginCallback();
      return true;
     }
   else {
      document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpanel").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("ctl00_body").style.overflowY = "hidden";

    return false;
    }
  }

    function LoginCallback() {
        LoadingPanel.Show();
        CallbackLoginCallback.PerformCallback();
    }
  </script>
```

**CallBack Event Client Side**
**Code Aspx**

```
<dx:ASPxCallback ID="ASPxCallbackLoginCallback" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="CallbackLoginCallback"
        OnCallback="ASPxCallbackLoginCallback_Callback">
</dx:ASPxCallback>

<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_login" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="login"  CssClass="login_btn" ImageUrl="images/Reg-login.png"
                                 OnClientClick="return ValidateLogin();" />
```

**CallBack Event Server Side**
**Code C#**

```
protected void ASPxCallbackLoginCallback_Callback(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxCallback.CallbackEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        objclsCandidate.Email = txtEmailId_ExistingUser.Text;
        CommonClass objCommonClass = new CommonClass();
        objclsCandidate.Password = objclsCrypto.EnCrypt(txtPassword.Text);
        DataSet ds = objclsCandidate.CheckLogin();
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["CandidateID"] = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ID"]);          
            string url = "JobDescription.aspx?JobId=" + Request.QueryString["JobId"].ToString();           
            ASPxWebControl.RedirectOnCallback(url);            

        }
        else
        {
           e.Result =  "false";                         
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        clsError.ShowErrorAlert(ee, Page);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was an extra call (return true) via this javascript Function. just comment return true part and let the call back do its part

**OLD**

```
function ValidateLogin() {

   Page_ClientValidate("login");
   if (Page_IsValid) {
      LoginCallback();
      return true;
     }
   else {
      document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpanel").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("ctl00_body").style.overflowY = "hidden";

    return false;
    }
  }
```

**Answer**

```
function ValidateLogin() {

   Page_ClientValidate("login");
   if (Page_IsValid) {
      LoginCallback();
      //return true;
     }
   else {
      document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divpanel").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("ctl00_body").style.overflowY = "hidden";

//    return false;
    }
 return false;
  }
```